# Phonegap events not firing

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, events, phonegap-plugins

I am creating a phonegap application for android and want to use some of the phonegap events like "resume", "pause", "backbutton" etc. but none of these events are getting fired except the "deviceready" event.
Following is my javascript code please check if I am making any mistake:

```
function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert("Device Ready");
            document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
        }

        // Handle the resume event
        //
        function onResume() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            alert("onResume");
            }, 0);
        }

        function onBackKeyDown() {
            // Handle the back button
            setTimeout(function() {
            alert("onBackKeyDown");
            }, 0);
        }
```

the alert inside 'onDeviceReady()' function is working.

please help,
thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about the backbutton event, because I don't use it. But the 'resume' one I do implement it like you do, and it works correctly. Did you try something easy like: document.addEventListener('resume', function(){alert('boom')}, false)? I run on cordova 4.0.0 for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Things you should try / check:

1) On HTML are you calling onLoad()?

2) On HTML are you referencing the js?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="example.js"></script> //(2)
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()"> //(1)
    </body>
</html>
```

3) On JS put the event listener onDeviceReady outside onLoad()

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onLoad() {}
function onDeviceReady() {
  alert("Device Ready");
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
```

Comment: I tried/checked everything you mentioned but its still not working

Comment: @sam did you ever get this working?  I'm having the same exact issue